# Need help to setup a datediff in SQL report

Tags: datediff

I need help to setup datediff in .RDL report. Here is a logic: to get the number of days between two dates (between modify date and now). Here is my =DateDiff(day,First(Fields!modifydate.Value, "DataSet1",Today())

Thank you

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: It is SQL reporting

Comment: I am also getting this error: "The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox60.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ uses an aggregate expression with the recursive/simple flag.  The recursive/simple flag is not allowed for First, Last, Previous, RowNumber, RunningValue and Aggregate."

Comment: =DateDiff(day,First(Fields!modifydate.Value, "DataSet1"),Now()) -- this did not work as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer: =DateDiff("d", Fields!modifydate.Value,TODAY()) or use  =Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime.DATEDIFF("d", Fields!modifydate.Value, Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime.TODAY)